# Can I use red stone in pocket edition?

Tags: minecraft-redstone, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am a Minecraft pocket edition player. Can I use redstone for things?

Comment: According to the [PE wikia](http://minecraftpocketedition.wikia.com/wiki/Redstone), at the moment you can only make Powered rail.

Answer (score 0):

In Minecraft Pocket Edition, the only things you can craft with redstone are Clocks, Powered Rails, and Compasses.